# Combine one column from multiple rows

Tags: php, mysql, sql

My problem may be a bit confusing, which is mostly why I have been unable to find a solution.

So, I have two tables, lets call them Main and Details. When data is inserted, there is ONE entry made into Main, and possibly multiple entries into Details.

So for example:

```
Main
id: 1
num: 55b
job: 100
```

-

```
Details:
id: 1,2,3
cost: 100, 50, 100
num: 55b, 55b, 55b
date: 01/01/14, ...
```

Now, I'm trying to pull this data and present it in a way that it will display all the dates with the same "num" in the same row. Maybe it's because I've been looking at it for a couple days, but I just can't figure out the logic on how to do this...

My SQL now:

```
$sql = "SELECT d.id, d.num, d.date, m.num, m.job
        FROM details d
        INNER JOIN main m ON m.num = d.num";
```

Not sure if I presented this in the most understandable way, so if you have any questions please feel free to ask ! Any suggestions appreciated.

Thanks

EDIT: As for GROUP BY, I've tried that and it only gets me one date but I need every date for each "num".

Context: This is for a "milestone" type app, where Main represents the task, and Details represents different milestones within the task. It will be presented in a way that it will show the user the due dates for each milestone, per job.

Right now, my table looks like this:

```
JOB# | mStone1 | mStone2 | mStone3 | ...
---------------------------------------------
100  |         |         | 01/01/14|       |
---------------------------------------------
100  | 01/25/14|         |         |
```

So in this example, I would like those two dates to be in the same row, for job 100

Comment: GROUP BY? But what do you want to with the other values when there are several entries for a day?

Comment: And what? What problems do you have?

Comment: If I use group by it only gets one of the dates entered, I need every date for that "num". Will post a little more info in OP

Comment: The query seems correct, you probably need to add a `WHERE` clause to it to get only specific entries and not the entire table(s).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `group_concat` for that

```
SELECT d.id, d.num, d.date, 
       group_concat(concat(m.num, ',', m.job) separator '|')
FROM details d
INNER JOIN main m ON m.num = d.num
GROUP BY d.id, d.num, d.date
```

Comment: with the usual proviso: group_concat has a limit on how long of a string it'll produce, usually set to 1024 chars. it'll silently truncate any extra bits that fall outside the max.

Comment: Can you please look at the update in the OP and let me know if this is still possible ? I would like all of the dates but not inside the same string, is that what GROUP_CONCAT would do ?

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't something like this be enough?

```
SELECT *
FROM details
LEFT JOIN main ON details.main_id=main.id
WHERE details.main_id=1;
```